# Checking whether a div is bound to knockout view model

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a function that is used to determine whether a div is bound to knockout view model. This is because i have a popup modal dialog in a page which is bound to view model on click using javascript. So after i close the modal dialog and click it to open again, it will shows multiple binding error.

Answer (score 3):

As described in Knockout documentation section [Using unobtrusive event handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html), there are two helper functions that might help you:

> - `ko.dataFor(element)` - returns the data that was available for binding    against the element
> - `ko.contextFor(element)` - returns the entire    binding context that was available to the DOM element.

In your case the function that you need is `dataFor`. If this function returns truthy value, this means the model is bound to this element, if the value is falsy, then nothing is bound to the element

For example, you have HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
```

And script:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable('John Doe')
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('div1'));
```

You have 2 div elements and only one of them is bound to a model. You can find data that is bound to an element by using

```
console.log(ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('div1')));  // prints object details
console.log(ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('div2')));  // prints undefined
```

So if you need to check if element is bound and perform some action you can use

```
if(ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('div1'))){
    console.log('element is bound');
}
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dduyneda/1/)

Comment: These can give a *false positive* if a parent element is bound with Knockout. So, in addition to checking for a truthy value, it's good to check that it is the viewmodel object you expect.

Comment: @MichaelBest That is an excellent point, however that depends on the logic of the application. If you only want to know if the element is bound, it is enough to check for truthy value, if you need to make sure the object is what you expected - you need to verify that